# SDE Connection raise exception

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I am supporting a .NET code that is running on ArcGIS Server 10.1, and communicating with ArcSDE Application Server 9.3

There is part of the code that is doing long loop.
And when it comes back to communicate to the database (to ArcSDE), it is raising this exception
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

It seems a timeout error.
Anybody has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: without more details- you should step through manual connect using the same parameters from your code. if that throws no exception you should verify port status between server and app server.

Comment: Did this previously work?  Have you tried connecting to Oracle using SQLPlus from that server?  Does the code open the SDE connection before looping or after?  Is there a firewall between the two servers?  Have you checked the SDE logs to see what happened?  Have you checked the oracle logs?